# (Wenn möglich) kostenlose Liste von deutschen Wörtern

Tags: resource, vocabulary

Ich brauche eine Liste von deutschen Wörtern für ein privates Projekt. Sie muss nicht sher ausführlich sein, 1000–3000 Wörter würden reichen. Im Internet habe ich keine gefunden. 
Wenn möglich sollten wie Wörter immer mit Absätzen getrennt sein, aber es sollte alles gehen solange man es “einfach” auslesen kann.

Comment: oder hier: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1893/what-is-the-best-free-word-frequency-list-in-german